# submit button get checkbox input safed in object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I have a question about how i can save the input from my checkboxes in an object when clicking on a button.
For now i just want it to see it in the console.
my code looks something like this:

```js
let UserInput = [];

const addUserInput = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let TextInput = {
    Name: document.getElementById('exampleInputName').value, //this is working
    InfoElektronik: $('#Info-Elektronik').click(function() { //this is not?
      console.log("Checkbox1 = " + $('#Info-Elektronik').prop('checked'));
    });
  };
};
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="agree" value="" id="Info-Elektronik">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Elektronik</label>
</div>
```

Comment: be clear in your question,i am not getting it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !!!. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery , and please, post your HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that InfoElektronik stores a function, not the actual return value.
Also in your click function, you log the value to the console.

I would do it like this:

```js
const TextInput = {
  Name: document.getElementById('exampleInputName').value
}

$('#Info-Elektronik').click(function() {
  textInput.InfoElektronik = ("Checkbox1 = " + $('#Info-Elektronik').prop('checked')).val();
})
```